# Unable to parse Yahoo Finance API JSON Data? Code included (Python Flask)

Tags: python, json, flask

A bit new to JSON... Does anyone know how to properly iterate through and grab the symbol and change for example? I've tried wrapping everything in json.loads and using strings, but I keep getting errors regarding tuples. FYI, I'm using ticker inside the string, but I changed it to be YHOO for this question for convenience of anyone trying to run the same code.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.compress import Compress
from flask import render_template
from httplib2 import Http
import json

http = Http()
app = Flask(__name__)
Compress(app)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['TESTING'] = True


@app.route('/<ticker>', methods=['GET'])
def check(ticker):
    yahoo_api = http.request("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20IN%20(%22YHOO%22)&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env")
    return yahoo_api[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yahoo_api[1]` is a string, use `json.loads` to get the json.

```
import json

from httplib2 import Http

yahoo_api = Http().request('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20IN%20(%22YHOO%22)&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env')
yahoo_json = json.loads(yahoo_api[1])
change = yahoo_json['query']['results']['quote']['Change']
symbol = yahoo_json['query']['results']['quote']['symbol']
```

Anthoer way is using `requests`, no worry about the json, it is esay to use.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20IN%20%28%22YHOO%22%29&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env')
change = r.json()['query']['results']['quote']['Change']
symbol = r.json()['query']['results']['quote']['symbol']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you might have forgotten to take the second part of the tuple (the content), although that seemed unlikely as you do do this for the return statement. Or maybe you forgot the UTF-8 decode?

```py
import json
import pprint
from httplib2 import Http

http = Http()

url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20IN%20(%22YHOO%22)&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env"
yahoo_api = http.request(url)
result = json.loads(yahoo_api[1].decode('utf-8'))
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Getting yahoo_api[1] works fine, what I'm wondering is how to specifically return the "symbol". I've tried yahoo_api[1]['query]['results']['symbol'], but it throws me an error. Here is a snippet of the returned json when you send a get request: {
  "query": {
    "count": 1,
    "created": "2015-12-09T23:38:56Z",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "results": {
      "quote": {
        "symbol": "aapl",
        "Ask": "115.74",
        "AverageDailyVolume": "46976200",

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str // Werkzeug Debugger